# Missing entries on the view menu of VB6

Tags: vb6

We have 2 computers in which the VB6 IDE is missing some major entries from its view menu. All entries after the "Watch Window" are missing. 
The two computers are with different OS (Win 7 and Win 10).
What could be the reason for that and how can we resolve this?

Here is an image of the menu with the missing entries:

[image: Menu with missing entries]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are much more items missing than watch window. The menus are customizable. Right click the menu bar and select Customize. There will then also be a Reset button.

Answer (score 0):

"The menus are customizable. Right click the menu bar and select Customize. There will then also be a Reset button." – GSerg

This resolved the problem.
Thanks